# Merge two strings into one string by condition and keeping order

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I have two methods that return the following strings:
The first method returns:

```
"Subj1
Subj3
Subj5
Subj7"
```

The second method returns:

```
"Subj1 (1)
Subj5 (6)
Subj4 (2)
Subj2 (8)"
```

How can I merge these to get a result like this:

```
"Subj1 (1)
Subj3
Subj5 (6)
Subj7
Subj4 (2)
Subj2 (8)"
```

Do I need to change the signature of the methods, so that these methods return results in some other form or something else?

The merge logic: if item in first string exists in second string then put the item from second string into result string if item in first string doesn't exists in second string then put the item from first string into result string

Comment: What are your actual criteria for checking if `"Subj1"` and `"Subj1 (1)"` are the same? Can you have `"Subj1 With A Longer Name"`?

Comment: Could you be more clear on the logic of the merge? Such as how you choose which items to drop and how the ordering of the final list is determined....

Comment: @Chris The merge logic:
if item in first string exists in second string then put the item from second string into result string
if item in first string doesn't exists in second string then put the item from first string into result string

Comment: @JamesMonger yes, I can have subj with longer name

Comment: @netwer So the order of items is irrelevant?

Comment: @netwer You say the methods return strings... how do you construct those strings? from lists? (which give access to .Contains and .Add etc) or from a database? etc etc

Comment: do these 2 methods HAVE to be returned that way. Collection of object would be favored for easier manipulation.

Comment: @netwer eh? You say if item exists... what is the magical concept of an item? do you mean a 'line' or part of a line? or a word?... e.g. you have "Subj1" in first string as the first line which isn't in second string in it's entirety ("Subj1 (6)" exists in second string) and it isn't in the resulting string? or do u also mean that if "(6)" was in first string that it would be in second string because of the "Subj5 (6)" ?!?!?!? confusing.com!

Comment: If you could bring some kind of proper delimiter (say a comma) between the words in the string, then this will help - https://dotnetfiddle.net/pWyelZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, you need two steps.

Step 1, split the strings on newline:

```
var s1 = "Subj1
Subj3
Subj5
Subj7"
var s2 = "Subj1 (1)
Subj5 (6)
Subj4 (2)
Subj2 (8)"
var s1words = split(s1, NewLine)
var s2words = split(s2, NewLine)
```

step 2, find each word in s1words in s2words, and if exists, use it:

```
var res
for each (word w in s1words) {
    for each (word x in s2words) {
        if (x.starts_with(w))
            res += x + NewLine
        else
            res += w + NewLine
```

not very efficient, but simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 = 
                "Subj1\n" +
                "Subj3\n" +
                "Subj5\n" +
                "Subj7\n";
            string input2 =

                 "Subj1 (1)\n" +
                 "Subj5 (6)\n" +
                 "Subj4 (2)\n" +
                 "Subj2 (8)\n";

            string[] stringArray= (input1 + input2).Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var groups = stringArray.GroupBy(x => x.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
            string output = string.Join("\n", groups.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Length).FirstOrDefault()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them together as lists and then group by and get one with suffix per each group:

```
var a1 = s1.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
var a2 = s2.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
var u = a1.Concat(a2);
var s = u.GroupBy(x => x.Split(' ')[0])
         .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Length).FirstOrDefault())
         .ToList();
String.Join("\r\n", s)
```